# Regarding Webservices configuration for mobile apps?

Tags: ios, web-services, app-store, titanium

I have one version of approved app in apple store with working webservices.
Now I have done some extra features and fixes in both mobile side and server side.
  Now I need to update my app with new binary to apple store for review suppose I done submission today but data base will update on after one week 
How can I maintain  that two webservices in app when we are sending to App Store review to my ios app.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I find in this situation is that you have some users on the old version of the app and others eventually will be on the new version of the app.  So, in my situation the old and new app need to continue working.  Since I can't break my old app version in favor of a new app version, I had to separate out the new functions into new versions if they required changing the parameters.  I started putting versions to the web service calls.

In essence, if I have to add functionality to a web service call, I create a separate function for that call.  On the server, the functions may call the same internal functions for capabilities, but I maintain the same parameter list and return values so my older app still works.

I've seen other apps mention you must upgrade your app when opening them.  I always assumed they had a web service call for status checks and information so that when the app was opened, returns from pause, etc. it checks that server first to see if it is still compatible with the web service.  If not, it throws up the message to update and doesn't continue doing any work for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing you can do is to offer multiple version of your APIs..
For example:

- v **1.0.0** of your app calls this url: http://www.server.com/api/v1/action
- v **2.0.0** of your app calls this url: http://www.server.com/api/v2/action

and so on..

In Titanium you can put all the urls you are going to call in the *config.js* file and update all at once when you want to switch to a new version of the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Revert if I am wrong in understanding your problem.
You have submitted your App to App store for review and expecting it to be reviewed and ready for use any time.
But your Database/Server Component will be updated after a week that is t+7 days.

If I am correct with understanding:
Solution is when you submit your App for Review there is a option to hold your Reviewed Version to a specified date, so that you can make sure your Database/Server components are in place.

Thanks
Amit Kalghatgi

Comment: that is app availability date .when apple reviewing my app  that time my  data based is not updated so that time what happen?

Comment: Sorry got your point now.... You have to deploy your changes to DB prior to review or else your App will crash during Review test. So you have to make App changes such that it should work on both old DB as well New DB.